# How do I repair rEFIt after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: refit

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my dual boot machine with Mac OS X and Ubuntu I no longer see rEFIt when I start the computer. Mac OS X is listed in the Grub menu but I can't start it from there. So how do I reinstall rEFIt from Ubuntu? The documentation only explains how to install rEFIt from OS X.

Comment: It should be easy. Hold down option (alt) during boot, and refit will appears along with other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by starting OS X from the installation DVD and setting the startup disk (in the Utilities menu) to the Mac OS X partition. After a restart I reinstalled rEFIt from OS X (two restarts are required to make rEFIt show up).